# (Google Sheet) Combine text and Date in Cell

Tags: excel, date, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get a Summary of multiple Cells into one Cell (for later use in GCalender). Trying to Concatenate a Date results into #ERROR! and similar questions and results found online dont work at all.

[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wg50KbM7fD_pFFBU12Y1ngTsgsnobjdLcLSJnrL1jHs/edit?usp=sharing)

Expected result should be:

="anything "&C2& " - " &TEXT(E2,"dd/mm/yyyy")

=anything thishappens - 10/03/2020

But Quoting the date alone will result in just a number (43900), and the TEXT and DATE formate will not work as found online or examples by Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might be in Europe or somewhere where they use ; instead of , as the parameter separators in formulas.  Try this:

="anything "&C2& " - " &TEXT(E2;"dd/mm/yyyy")

Comment: Its always the stupidest things, thanks for the help :)